# How do i wireup NServiceBus' SqlSaga in a test scenario?

Tags: testing, nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/testing/ has a very neat example of how to test a simple Saga. Unfortunately it does not explain, how to do the same with a SqlSaga - ie. a Saga with persistence of state to a database.

Given this saga:

```
public class SomeFancySaga : SqlSaga<MySagaData>,
    IAmStartedByMessages<ImportantCommand>
{
    protected override string CorrelationPropertyName => nameof(Data.MyPrimaryKey);

    protected override void ConfigureMapping(IMessagePropertyMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.ConfigureMapping<ImportantCommand>(x => x.CommandId);
    }

    public async Task Handle(ImportantCommand command, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (Data.State == MyState.ReadyForUse)
            <do some stuff>
    }
    ...
}
```

If I try to write test-code like the example in the link, I would do something like this:

```
// arrange
var context = new NServiceBus.Testing.TestableMessageHandlerContext();
var command = ImportantCommand.Create();
var sut = new CreateSomeFancySaga();

// act
sut.Handle(command, context);

// assert
...
```

The call to sut.Handle() will throw a NullReferenceException, because **the Saga property Data has not been initialized**.

How do I correctly wireup the saga for testing so that:

1. Data is initialized
2. A real database connection is not really needed

Comment: Problem 1 can be solved by initialising SUT as **var sut = new CreateSomeFancySaga() { Data = new MySagaData() }** - but I am not sure if it helps with problem 2.

Comment: Problem 2 is actually moot, as the Handle method is tested isolated. This means that nothing calls the persistence logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a related code sample showing unit testing in more detail: https://docs.particular.net/samples/unit-testing/. That includes a couple of tests for saga (`SagaTests.cs`).

You can take this as a starting point and modify the saga tests in the following way:

1. Add `NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql` package.
2. Modify the `DiscountPolicy` policy saga to inherit from `SqlSaga` instead of a `Saga`.
3. Resolve compilation errors (add missing method and property, you can keep them empty, plus remove the `ConfigureHowToFindSaga` method).

I hope that helps, but let me know if there's anything missing or your scenario can't be tested this way.

Comment: That was also the solution I got to, as stated in the comment to my OP. I think that I was too absorbed with the fact, that I was testing something with built-in SQL persistance, when in fact I wasn't: I am only testing the Handle() method fully isolated. So it didn't really matter that it was SqlSaga - except for the need to Add NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql package. Maybe you could add that piece of info to your docs - it would be very useful.